# People don't seem to downvote much - is this due to the loss of reputation incurred?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes

I notice that there is not much downvoting going on, even though I see a lot of (what I perceive as) inaccurate or simply poor answers.

Why are these not downvoted? Could it be that  newbies don't want to lose reputation when they do this?

Is there any way to remedy this (or it is maybe a non-issue)?

Comment: People are just too nice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with nice people -  just that stackexchange is about separating good answers from bad. Part of this process is upvoting, the other is downvoting.

Answer (score 4):

Good question.  I have no issues with downvoting.  I think that there is clearly a lack of upvoting sometimes too.  The order of activity goes views>comments or answers>upvote>downvote.  It seems that people love to look and read but they don't seem to want to pull the trigger on a simple vote either way. Down voting is at the bottom of the pile as part of a larger issue of inactivity I think.  Yes there are plenty of upvotes, but it is trivial in relation to some of the view #s sometimes.